# ‘setprecision’ is not a member of ‘std’

Tags: c++, string

Errors:

```
~> g++ ssstring.cpp
ssstring.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ssstring.cpp:12:31: error: ‘setprecision’ is not a member of ‘std’
ssstring.cpp:12:52: error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’
ssstring.cpp:12:74: error: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
ssstring.cpp:13:30: error: ‘setprecision’ is not a member of ‘std’
ssstring.cpp:13:51: error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’
ssstring.cpp:13:73: error: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
ssstring.cpp:14:28: error: ‘setprecision’ is not a member of ‘std’
ssstring.cpp:14:49: error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’
ssstring.cpp:14:71: error: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
anisha@linux-trra:~>
```

Code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    // Convert `lat`, `lons`, and `vehicleId` to string.
    float selectedPointLat = 2.2;
    float selectedPointLng = 2.3;
    float vehicleId        = 1.0;

    std :: stringstream floatToStringLat, floatToStringLng, floatToStringVehicleId;

    floatToStringLat       << std :: setprecision (std :: numeric_limits<float> :: digits10 + 1); floatToStringLat  << selectedPointLat;
    floatToStringLng       << std :: setprecision (std :: numeric_limits<float> :: digits10 + 1); floatToStringLng << selectedPointLng;
    floatToStringVehicleId << std :: setprecision (std :: numeric_limits<float> :: digits10 + 1); floatToStringVehicleId << vehicleId;

}
```

Comment: Don't include `string.h`... do you mean `string` or `cstring`?

Comment: You'll need `<limits>` for `std::numeric_limits` btw.

Comment: Remember you can find what headers things are in by looking them up in the C++ reference: [`setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/), [`numeric_limits`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/).

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You need to include header `<iomanip>` for [std::setprecision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) and `<limits>` for [std::numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits). These references tell you which header to include.

Comment: Thanks! My code used to compile without including `<iomanip>`. what made it not to compile now?

Comment: @LivneRosenblum it could due to a compiler and/or standard library upgrade or change. A header that included `iomanip` in one version didn't in another one. The C++ standard doesn't restrict which standard headers can be included in others, but it does tell you which headers you need for any given symbol.